# JS Format Hexadeical String in every 2 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a irregular string length.
I want to add space in every 2digits.
626C75652073637265656E
=>
62 6C 75 65 20 73 63 72 65 65 6E

or 
626C756520736372
=>
62 6C 75 65 20 73 63 72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.replace` for this, replacing every two word characters with those two word characters plus a space:

```js
const str = '626C75652073637265656E';
console.log(str.replace(/\w\w/g, '$& '));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use this:

```js
var s = '626C756520736372'

var n = [...s].reduce((r,e,i) => r+e+' '.repeat(i%2),'').trim()

console.log(n)
```